# Elliptic Operator , a priori bounds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, differential-operators

suppose we have the following operator :
\begin{equation*}
L [u] = 
\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} a_{ij}(x)u_{x_ix_j}(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i(x) u_{x_i}(x) + c(x) u(x) = f(x) , x \in \Omega
\end{equation*}
where $c(x)\leq -c_0<0$
in addition 
\begin{equation}
u\Big|_{\partial \Omega} = 0 , 
\end{equation}
I want to prove that 
\begin{equation}
u(x) \leq \max \Big\{0,\max_{\Omega} \frac{f(x)}{-c_0} \Big\},  \forall  x \in \overline\Omega
\end{equation}
I've tried many things which follow the idea that i want a function $S$ such that $S\Big|_{\partial \Omega}=\max_{\Omega} \frac{f(x)}{-c_0} $  and $L[S]\geq 0$ and $S\geq u$. From the maximum principle we have that there is no positive maximum of S in $\Omega$, so positive maximum doesn't exist ($S\geq 0$) or it exists at the boundary. In other words :
\begin{equation}
u \leq S \leq \max\Big\{ 0 , \max_{\partial \Omega}S \Big\}= \max\Big\{ 0, \max_{\Omega} \frac{f}{-c_0}\Big\} 
 \end{equation}

Comment: It's easier. Just look at the maximum of u. If it is on the boundary, then it is zero. If interior, then it is $$f/-c$$.

Comment: I noticed an error at my proof , so i can't conlude what we are looking for . I think we must take different cases for $\max f \geq 0$ or $\max f < 0$

Comment: So we have that , if $x_0$ is the maximum where $x_0 \in \Omega$:
\begin{equation}
L[u](x_0) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} a_{ij}u_{x_ix_j}(x_0) + c u(x_0) = f(x_0) \leq \max_{\Omega} f
\end{equation}
where $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} a_{ij}u_{x_ix_j}(x_0)\leq 0$

Comment: Ok, so $c(x_0)u(x_0) \geq f(x_0)$. Since $c$ is negative, you get $u(x_0) \leq f(x_0)/c(x_0)$.

Comment: So, if $\max_{\Omega} f \leq 0 ($ otherwise $\max ( 0 , \frac{\max_{\Omega} f}{-c_0} )= 0   $) so $\frac{\max_{\Omega} f}{c(x_0)}\leq \frac{\max_{\Omega} f}{-c_0}$ and $\frac{f(x_0)}{c(x_0)} \geq \frac{\max_{\Omega} f}{c(x_0)}$ and we can't conclude that $\frac{ f(x_0)}{c(x_0)} \leq \frac{\max_{\Omega} f}{-c_0}$

Comment: I would just use $\max_\Omega \frac{f}{c}$ instead.

Comment: Sorry @Jeff i saw a mistake at my question here and i fixed it . 
The wrong was that , i had wrote : $c(x)\leq c_0 < 0$ . But the right is $c(x)\leq - c_0 < 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is three cases : 
1) positive maximum doesn't exist ( so $u \leq 0$ )
2) positive maximum is at boundary ( there is no way to be at the boundary because $u|_{\partial \Omega}=0$)

3) positive maximum exist at the internal point
So , let's denote with $x_0$ the point at which the positive maximum is located so we then have :

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} a_{ij}u_{x_ix_j}(x_0) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_{i}u_{x_i}(x_0) + c(x_0)u(x_0) = f(x_0)
\end{equation*}
but obviously  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_{i}u_{x_i}(x_0)=0$ because $x_0$ is located the maximum , and for the same reason  $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} a_{ij}u_{x_ix_j}(x_0)\leq 0$. Also we have from our hypothesis that $u(x_0) \leq 0 $ and we can conclude that $f(x_0) \leq 0$ .
So 
\begin{equation}
c(x_0)u(x_0) \geq f(x_0)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x_0) \leq \frac{f(x_0)}{c(x_0)} \leq\frac{f(x_0)}{-c_0} \leq \frac{\max_{\Omega}f}{-c_0}
\end{equation}
The last holds because $c(x)\leq -c_0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{c(x)}\geq \frac{1}{-c_0} \Rightarrow \frac{f(x_0)}{c(x)}\leq \frac{f(x_0)}{-c_0}$ .